# Why is my dynamically added (and button A replacing) button B clicked by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, button, dynamic, replace

This is my problem:

1. User taps *button A*.
2. This triggers a jQuery animation hiding *button A*.
3. On completion of this animation, *button B* is shown by a jQuery animation at the exact same position.
4. jQuery acts as if *button B* was tapped.

This seems very strange to me and is causing a terrible user experience. Can anyone help me fix this? Here's the javascript code though I think it's a general problem of jQuery:

```
function showbuttonB(element){
   $(element).animate({ opacity: '0', marginRight: '-50px'}, 230, function(){
      $(element).append("<span class='buttonB'><a href='mailto:XXXXXXXX'><div class='icon'>ButtonB</div></a></span>");
      $(element).find('.buttonB').animate({
         display: 'toggle',
         marginRight: '0px'
      }, 230);
   });
}

$(".buttonA").live('touchend mouseup', function() {
  showbuttonB(this);
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="buttonA">ButtonA</div>
```

Comment: Code? Cannot guess everything from this.

Comment: The problem is at line No.3 **...**

Comment: I added the code though I really would have guessed someone ran into this problem before. It's a general thing. You replace a button on tap and jQuery does it but also applies your tap to the new button.

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML to go with your code.  We need to be able to see your specific issue in order to reliably help.

Comment: @jfriend00. he updated the question. I think I got it, what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't act like the bButton was clicked, the problem is that new button is inside a hidden element.

Check [**this working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gBwrG/3/)

#### Code:

```
function showbuttonB(element) {
    $(element).animate({
        opacity: '0',
        marginRight: '-50px'
    }, 230, function() {
        $('#foo').append("<span class='buttonB'><a href='mailto:XXXXXXXX'><div class='icon'>ButtonB</div></a></span>");
        $('#foo').find('.buttonB').animate({
            display: 'toggle',
            marginRight: '0px'
        }, 230);
    });
}

$(".buttonA").live('touchend mouseup', function() {
    showbuttonB(this);
});​
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="buttonA">ButtonA</div>
<span id="foo"> </span>
```

​